# Unable to install an npm package

Tags: node.js, github, npm, npm-install, package.json

I tried many different ways to install [this](https://github.com/postmen/node-cloud-print) package:
npm install cloud-print
npm install https://github.com/postmen/node-cloud-print.git
and so on...

And every time i get the following output:

```html
`npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:211:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  git+ssh://git@github.com/postmen/google-api-nodejs-client.git resetting remote C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-postmen-google-api-nodejs-client-git-21a89f46 because of error: { Error: Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url
npm WARN addRemoteGit
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:211:12)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
npm WARN addRemoteGit   killed: false,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   code: 1,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   signal: null,
npm WARN addRemoteGit   cmd: 'git -c core.longpaths=true config --get remote.origin.url' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/postmen/google-api-nodejs-client.git C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-postmen-google-api-nodejs-client-git-21a89f46: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-postmen-google-api-nodejs-client-git-21a89f46'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/postmen/google-api-nodejs-client.git C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-postmen-google-api-nodejs-client-git-21a89f46: Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/postmen/google-api-nodejs-client.git C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-postmen-google-api-nodejs-client-git-21a89f46: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/postmen/google-api-nodejs-client.git C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-postmen-google-api-nodejs-client-git-21a89f46:
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/postmen/google-api-nodejs-client.git C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-postmen-google-api-nodejs-client-git-21a89f46: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/postmen/google-api-nodejs-client.git C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-postmen-google-api-nodejs-client-git-21a89f46: and the repository exists.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "cloud-print"
npm ERR! node v7.4.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/postmen/google-api-nodejs-client.git C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-postmen-google-api-nodejs-client-git-21a89f46
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-ssh-git-github-com-postmen-google-api-nodejs-client-git-21a89f46'...
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Tmunot\npm-debug.log`
```

I also tried to download the directory to node_modules and configure it manually in package.json, but i didn't have success doing that.

Any ideas?

Comment: What output? Some text is missing

Comment: I had a problem in the indentation, now it's ok

Comment: If it is a link: try to add its content directly to your question and mark it as code

Comment: from what I see the script gets the repo via ssh so you need to pay attention here `Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

Comment: I'm going to guess it's because you're using `git+ssh://` and don't have an SSH on your profile.  Try [Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/).

Comment: i followed the instructions there and done npm install git+ssh://git@github.com/postmen/node-cloud-print.git, still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Not all packages support installation from github. If it's [available in npm (correct package now linked)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloud-print), I'd favor that.

Should it not be available in npm, then know that it appears to have a build process (given the existence of `grunt` commands). You should clone it, build it and use NPM to pull in a "built" copy.

You'd use the method described here once built: [npm install <folder>](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: In fact, yes, that does appear to be the correct package for the github project.

Comment: Indeed. Not sure if you created it, but there is an issue open for the package/project owner. https://github.com/postmen/node-cloud-print/issues/6

Comment: i tried to do the following: git clone https://github.com/postmen/node-cloud-print.git and then npm install -g ./node-cloud-print and i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in your npm version. The npm version is too new for this package. Package `cloud-print` is outdated. Nobody supports the package. Maybe be npm will support that type of packages in 5.1 version.

JFYI: `npm i cloud-print` result on different node+npm versions:

- node v8.1.3 npm v5.0.3 errors
- node v7.10.0 npm v4.2.0 work
- node v6.11.0 npm v3.10.10 work
- node v4.4.7 npm v2.15.8 work

**Solution use Node.js v.6**

Could you use Node.js v6? On this the latest support version you can work this package.